# Trying to setup cronjob auto-browser or run scripts in Python or PHP

Tags: server, python, php, cron

The situation was I wanted to set up cronjob for webserver on Ubuntu,

the `php` / `python` script file would be several sql function,
then run automatically update multiple tables.

but after few research, I found:

- Ubuntu contain at least 3 PHP
- 1, apache2 PHP
- 2, client PHP
- 3, cgi PHP ( which I'm not fully understand )
- with some dig: [what-is-difference-between-php-cli-and-php-cgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315714/what-is-difference-between-php-cli-and-php-cgi)(still don't, just knowing different)

First I try running `scripts.php` on Ubuntu terminal such as

```
$ crontab -e
$ * * * * */usr/bin/php8.0 /var/www/myproject/scripts.php
```

but Ubuntu terminal return `could not find driver`, tried re-install `pdo-mysql` in above PHP just still there;

- I'm afraid `admin` blocked user `scripts` / `cli-php` might be security concern;
- also tried `which php` to locate executable php, and used `/usr/bin/php` ;
- [how-to-get-path-of-the-php-binary-on-server-where-it-is-located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656678/how-to-get-path-of-the-php-binary-on-server-where-it-is-located)
- [php-root-directory](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/php/php-root-directory/)

Currently running directly open the URL with browser.

```
$crontab -e
$* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && firefox https://localhost/project/cron/scripts.php
```

the `.sh scripts` using;

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set maximum amount of remaining firefox processes here
MAX_PROC=2

let COUNT=$(pgrep firefox | wc -l)
for (( i=1; i<=COUNT-MAX_PROC; i++ ))
do
  PID=$(pgrep -o firefox)
  kill $PID
# sleep 3
done
```

**terminal `pkill` work like charm**

```
30 0 * * * pkill -f firefox.sh
```

Another option `python` `selenium` since the browser needs be gone;

but there's new problem that says:
`Browser is under remote (reason: Marionette)`
and opening a blank page;

**after few test even the blank page the scripts still work but blank;**

- some of the answers saying turn off `hardware accelerate`
- or go to `about:config` and disable `marionette` which I CAN'T;
- [remove_the_remote_control_robot_with_red_and_grey/](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/q4rp07/remove_the_remote_control_robot_with_red_and_grey/)

After some work still need some help:

- How to upgrade `pdo_mysql` in `cli-php` without modified `apache-php`;
- What would be the proper way to disable `Browser is under remote`;

Welcome any suggestion,
Thanks for any help.
both `Python` / `PHP` acceptable!

Comment: Usually you ask one question. When you ask multiple questions you get exponential answers.

Comment: Really good suggestion. Thank you for point out.

Answer (score 0):

Why would there be a browser opened when you're using `wget` in cron?

For the scheduled task with a local PHP file, this is generally the easier option:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/wget --no-check-certificate -q "https://localhost/project/cron/scripts.php" -O /root/output.txt
```

No browser will open for this, and the SSL certificate will not be checked for validation (as it's a local site, so it's *probably* trusted).

Comment: Sorry used wrong code, I just using `wget` on the other cron, thank you!